# Activity indicator works but shows randomly afterwards

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button on my site that when clicked makes an ajax call.  I wanted to show an activity indicator and am using this code:

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#ajax-loader-example').show();
 }).ajaxStop(function () {
  $('#ajax-loader-example').hide();
  });
```

This works great, and shows the indicator and ends at the end of the ajax process.  But if you stay on the page without clicking the button or doing anything, the indicator will show again and then stop.

Is there any way I can stop the indicator from showing again randomly?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't ajax calls being made on some kind of timer? Watch your network traffic in the dev tools to find out.

Comment: as Joe points out above, make sure no other calls are being made. Problem is, you're not using `$.ajax` you're using `$( document ).ajaxStart` which applies to all ajax calls

Comment: Also note: "`If $.ajax() or $.ajaxSetup() is called with the global option set to false, the .ajaxStart() method will not fire.`"

Comment: Thanks..I'm going to check the calls..yes, using document because I read that was correct with the most recent versions of jquery.  I don't have the global option set to false.